# Using bearer token or Oauth in case of docker private registry

Tags: docker, authorization, docker-registry

I want to have oauth/bearer token to authenticate my private registry. please let me know the steps.

docker login needs id and password, so how to pass token?

New to this domain, so need help.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to perform API calls in the following order:

- Authenticate and get the token

  > https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/oauth/
  >
  > https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/token/
- Using the token, get the digest for the image and use that digest to pull the corresponding layer via API calls mentioned in the link below.

  > https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#pulling-an-image